# Trello board with no admin

Tags: trello

How is it possible to have a board in Trello, that has no admin user on it?
The board is not part of any organization, I am the only user on it (I use this board mainly for managing my tasklist), but I just discovered that I am not an admin. (All because of background colours...)

I have no idea how this happened, to the best of my knowledge a single admin cannot be removed or un-admin'ed, until there is at least one more user with admin privileges.

How can I get admin rights on my board back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always email Trello Support (support@trello.com).  I've had a couple issues that have been resolved within a couple days.  They're pretty good at resolving issues quickly.

Comment: Good idea, just did that. Thanks.